# Collapsible nav within three column layout

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a header that is split into three columns, these are logo, searchbar and nav.

I followed this for the nav section: https://codepen.io/macsupport/pen/bKFzD as I'm new to bootstrap and am still figuring it out.

When this is desktop size I want my menu to be expanded horizontally and only when it gets down to tablet size collapse it to the menu icon.

However, I think the fact that it is in a column a third of the size of the screen to begin with that it will always be collapsed.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<header class="fixed-top" id="header">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
        <img src="media/logo.png" alt="Logo" class="logo">
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
        <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0 search">
          <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
          <button class="btn btn-secondary my-2 my-sm-0 orange" type="submit">
            <img src="media/icons/search.png" alt="Search" class="icon">
          </button>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse text-center" role="navigation">
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#nav">
              <img src="media/icons/menu.png" alt="Menu" class="icon">
            </button>
          </div>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="nav">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <li class="nav-item align-middle"><a class="nav-link grey" href="">Home</a></li>
              <li class="nav-item align-middle"><a class="nav-link grey" href="store">Products</a></li>
              <li class="nav-item align-middle"><a class="nav-link grey" href="blog">Blog</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

### Edit

Is there a way to get it to collapse in from the side underneath the actual header like in this image

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<header class="fixed-top" id="header">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">
        <img src="media/logo.png" alt="Logo" class="logo">
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-5">
        <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0 search">
          <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
          <button class="btn btn-secondary my-2 my-sm-0 orange" type="submit">
       <img src="media/icons/search.png" alt="Search" class="icon">
      </button>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-5">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
       <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
              <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown
         </a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                  <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                </div>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: There was a change in the markup and a couple of classes were missing. Kindly refer this page - https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/navbar/

Comment: Thanks that is exactly what I needed. Just a quick follow on question, is there any way to get it to expand from the side under the header without expanding the whole header down to accomodate it. Not asking for a solution just a point in the right direction would be great.

Comment: Do you mean that the `nav` should have it's own row below the logo and search?

Comment: Hi yeah see the new image so the collapsible part of the menu is in red and the rest of the header is in the blue-ish color, but I want it to remain the way it is for desktop, is that possible?

Comment: Then you'll have to collapse the nav in the first place and give an appropriate height & background to the header